# Smooch iOS SDK: can't add SKTMenuItemCamera to list of menu items

Tags: ios, info.plist, ios-camera, smooch

I'm trying to add the camera option to the list of menu items in Smooch. I've followed the steps in the [docs](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-ios-sdk/#menu-items), those being...

1) Add **SKTMenuItemCamera** to my **settings.allowedMenuItems** in AppDelegate.m

```
SKTSettings* settings = [SKTSettings settingsWithAppId:@"myAppId"];
settings.allowedMenuItems = @[SKTMenuItemCamera, SKTMenuItemGallery, SKTMenuItemDocument];
```

2) Add the **NSCameraUsageDescription** key and description string to my Info.plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ... more keys and descriptions
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera permission is required to send images to $(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    ... more keys and descriptions
</dict>
</plist>
```

For some reason the camera option isn't being displayed, though the photo gallery and document upload options are. I haven't seen this problem reported anywhere else. Help!

I'm using Smooch (6.10.2)

Comment: Are you running on the simulator or a real device? If you are on the simulator the camera option will never display because the sim has no camera

Comment: I’m running it on a real device.

Comment: Have you also set `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in your info.plist?

Comment: That was it. I had `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and it slipped past me that those are two different things. Thanks!